# How to solve a python "test" stage error on Jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins, testing, continuous-integration, cd

I am trying to build a CI/CD flow on Jenkins. I have my file updated on Jenkins but at a certain test stage, the code test fails meanwhile it does not fail in my local machine.

**The test error on Jenkins is shown:**

```
+ python cidr_convert_api/python/tests.py
..E..E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_invalid_mask_to_cidr (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cidr_convert_api/python/tests.py", line 30, in test_invalid_mask_to_cidr
    self.assertEqual('Invalid', self.convert.mask_to_cidr('0.0.0.0'))
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WL_Interview/cidr_convert_api/python/convert.py", line 17, in mask_to_cidr
    values = list(map(lambda x: 8 - math.log2(2**8 - int(x)), values))
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WL_Interview/cidr_convert_api/python/convert.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    values = list(map(lambda x: 8 - math.log2(2**8 - int(x)), values))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log2'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_valid_mask_to_cidr (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cidr_convert_api/python/tests.py", line 17, in test_valid_mask_to_cidr
    self.assertEqual('1', self.convert.mask_to_cidr('128.0.0.0'))
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WL_Interview/cidr_convert_api/python/convert.py", line 17, in mask_to_cidr
    values = list(map(lambda x: 8 - math.log2(2**8 - int(x)), values))
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WL_Interview/cidr_convert_api/python/convert.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    values = list(map(lambda x: 8 - math.log2(2**8 - int(x)), values))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log2'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

**The passed test on my local machine is shown thus:**

[Image of passed test on machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3fCZ.png)

Then finally, a view of the build is shown thus:
[jenkins dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGAUg.png).

I have a dockerfile, the API file and other middleware and if you need any of them for more context, please request.

I'd really appreciate who could help in. Thanks!

Comment: Did you name a module or package `math`?

Comment: Yes, I did. @KlausD.

Comment: Well then: don't do that!

Answer (score 0):

Due to the dissimilarity between my local PC python and the Jenkins Python, I had to pass the python test command from docker and it ran comfortably.

I just added `RUN python ./tests.py` and it worked like magic.

thanks!